# MySQL/JDBC Encoding Hell

Tags: mysql, jdbc, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I'm getting into encoding hell by trying to read Strings from a longtext column with MySQL Connector/J. As far as I can tell, the database is fully utf8.

```
sql>show variables like '%char%'
```

gives

```
----------------------------------
|character_set_client     |utf8mb4
|character_set_connection |utf8mb4
|character_set_database   |utf8mb4
|character_set_filesystem |binary
|character_set_results    |utf8mb4
|character_set_server     |utf8mb4
|character_set_system     | utf8
|character_sets_dir       |C:\Users\gek\xampp\mysql\share\charsets\
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The column in question is also utf8:

```
SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE table_schema = "empa" AND table_name = "project" AND column_name = "airborne1Data"
```

gives

```
character_set_name
utf8
```

This is how I connect to the database via JDBC:

```
Connection con;     
private Database() {
    //load Driver
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("charSet", "utf8"); 
        prop.put("user", "root");
        prop.put("password", "");       
        this.con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:mysql://" + dbServer + "/" +dbName,prop);  
        } catch{...}
```

So I guess, MySQL Connector/J should also know, that I want to read my strings as utf8, but it won't:

```
ResultSet sql = statement.executeQuery("Select * FROM project WHERE project.id=" + projectId);
if (sql.first()) {
    System.out.println(sql.getString("airborne1Data"));
}
```

will fail as german umlauts (ä/ö/ü). They seem to be encoded in latin-1 (analysing the bytes shows that ö=#F6).

I'm by no stretch an expert in encoding and I'm quite surprised that this is still an issue in 2021. My approach until now was simply "Do everything in utf8 and it'll work".
Is there any other place I forgot, where the encoding can be changed?

Comment: Is that ö=#F6 the output of `System.out.println`? Java uses Unicode for its internal encoding but `System.out.println` transforms to platform-specific encoding (e.g. cp1252 for windows) by default.

Comment: No, I´ve checked the hex-values by saving the String to a file and then viewing it in hexedit. System.out.println just shows a questionmark in a square.

Comment: So how did you save the String to a file? Did you specify an encoding when creating the `Writer`? If you didn't then we are back to it using default encoding, i.e. cp1252. As a rule, java handles its internal character-encoding quite well, but anytime you have input or output of characters it is your job to take care of the encoding.

Comment: Yeah, that´s it! Specifiing the charset in the writer did the trick. I somehow asumed that it had to fail earlier as it didn´t show up correct in the println, but this seems to be related to my eclipse-console. Thanks a lot! Could you please write your comment as an answer, than I´ll accept it.